# Find conditions for an equation involves conditional probability to hold.

Tags: probability

The question is as follow:

For events A and B, under what conditions does the equation 
$P(A)=P(A|B)+P(A|B^C)$ hold?

What I know is that there is a theorem states that $P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^C)P(B^C)$, so I try to start from here. However if letting $P(B)=1$, then $B^C$ would be the null event and $P(A|B^C)$ will not be well-defined. Similarly if letting $P(B^C)=1$. Is there anyone willing to give me a hint to start with? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$P(A) = P(A|B) + P(A|B') \ge P(A|B) P(B) + P(A|B') P(B') = P(A)$ with equality exactly when ( $P(A|B) = 0$ or $P(B) = 1$ ) and ( $P(A|B') = 0$ or $P(B') = 1$ ).